# How can I only call a BigQuery table each dag run instead of every time Airflow refreshes?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I have a DAG that queries a table, pulling data from it, and which also uses a **ShortCircuitOperator** to check if the DAG needs to run, which is also based on a BQ table name. The issue is this currently queries the table every time Airflow refreshes. The table is small (each query is less than 1 kb) but I'm concerned this will get more expensive as its scaled up. Is there a way to only query this table each DAG run instead?

Here's a code snippet to show what's going on:

```
client = bigquery.Client()
def create_query_lists(list_type):
    query_job = client.query(
        """
        SELECT filename
        FROM `requests`
        """
    )
    results = query_job.result()
    results_list = []
    for row in results:
        results_list.append(row.filename)
    return results_list

   def check_contents():
        if len(create_query_lists()) == 0:
            raise ValueError('Nothing to do')
            return False
        else:
            print("There's stuff to do")
            return True
#Create task to check if data being pulled is empty, if so fail so other tasks don't run
    check_list = ShortCircuitOperator(
        task_id="check_column_not_empty",
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=check_list_contents
        )
    
check_list #do subsequent tasks which use the same function
```

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood your need, you want to execute tasks only if the result of `SQL` query is not empty.

In this case you can also use `BranchPythonOperator`, example :

```py
import airflow
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()


def create_query_lists(list_type):
    query_job = client.query(
        """
        SELECT filename
        FROM `requests`
        """
    )
    results = query_job.result()
    results_list = []
    for row in results:
        results_list.append(row.filename)
    return results_list


def check_contents():
    if len(create_query_lists()) == 0:
        return 'KO'
    else:
        return 'OK'


with airflow.DAG(
        "your_dag",
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    branching = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='file_exists',
        python_callable=check_contents,
        provide_context=True,
        op_kwargs={
            'param': 'param'
        },
        dag=dag
    )

    ok = DummyOperator(task_id='OK', dag=dag)
    ko = DummyOperator(task_id='KO', dag=dag)

    fake_task = DummyOperator(task_id='fake_task', dag=dag)

    (branching >>
     ok >>
     fake_task)

    branching >> ko
```

- The `BranchPythonOperator` executes the query, if the result is not empty, it returns `OK`, otherwise `KO`
- We create 2 `DummyOperator` one for `OK`, the other for `KO` (2 branches)
- Depending on the result, we will go to the `OK` or `KO` branch
- The `KO` branch will finish the DAG without other tasks
- The `OK` branch will continue the DAG with tasks that follow (`fake_task`) in my example